# Get the total count of employees reporting to the Supervisor MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called EMPLOYEE which has the following columns.

```
DESC EMPLOYEE;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Fname     | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Minit     | char(4)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Lname     | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Ssn       | char(9)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Bdate     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Address   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sex       | char(4)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Salary    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Super_ssn | char(9)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Dno       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Super_ssn is the foreign_key which refers to Ssn in the same table. I have to get the first and last name of the employee who is also a supervisor. I am able to achieve this by the following query.

```
SELECT E.Fname, E.Lname FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE S WHERE S.Super_ssn = E.Ssn;
```

I want to get the total number of employees directly supervised by each supervisor. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do that.

```
SELECT E.Fname, E.Lname, COUNT(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE S WHERE S.Super_ssn = E.Ssn GROUP_BY E.Ssn;
```

I am sure what I did above is wrong. Can someone help me?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get multiple rows from the first query?

Comment: Yeah I get multiple rows for the first query.

Comment: Do you need to get the name and last name of the supervisor and also the total employees that are supervised in the same result? If not, could you please post the expected result

Comment: I just need the names of the employees who are directly supervised by each supervisor. Actually I figured it out is this right?
SELECT E.Fname, E.Lname, COUNT(*) AS Direct_Employees FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE S WHERE E.Ssn = S.Super_ssn GROUP BY S.Super_ssn;

Comment: I don't think ssns should be used a primary keys. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query